# Is it possible to include framework in C++ project in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, frameworks

I have a C++ project generated from Cmake to Xcode. My project is just some static and dynamic libraries. I want to include some 3rd party frameworks to it. 
Is it possible? Is there any chance to include? Or I should completely redesign the project to Cocoa app? 
I haven't access to the framework source code.
Work with Xcode 9.2.

Comment: It is possible but I'm not sure if it is possible with all the frameworks. I've done it with Carbon, Foundation and AppKit. It should be the same with all the others but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use Cocoa frameworks in pure C++ project.

But you can just create an obj-c project and include all of your existing sources inside - everything will work. Just remember to use `.mm` extension for the source files, calling C++ code.

You can use swift as well, but that will require to create a wrapper for C++ code.